# Spring Boot with more context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a spring boot with the main class with `@SpringBootApplication` (so it is has implied tags `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@ComponentScan`, and `@Configuration`).

What happens if I create another class with annotation `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan`?  Do I create another container of beans? In this way the beans are duplicates? Is a good way create more `@Configuration` class?  `@Configuration` create a container of beans?  If yes the two containers share the bean?

I need to understand these question.

Comment: Please refer spring framework and Spring-boot documentation from their official site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define multiple @configuration in spring boot as 
Matias Elorriaga mentioned.
@Configuration equals to `<beans>` tag in spring xml which hold many `<bean>` (equal to @Bean) inside of this, same a class with annotation `@Configuration` say hey you can define multiple beans inside me
e.f:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("message");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        final LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return sessionLocaleResolver;
    }

}
```

Also if you have 2 different class with same type of Bean
e.g. class: SpringConfigA have Composite bean

```
@Configuration
 public class SpringConfigA {

@Bean
     public Composite composite() {
         Composite c = new Composite();
         return c;             
     }
}
```

and another class SpringConfigB have same Composite bean

```
@Configuration
 public class SpringConfigB {

@Bean
     public Composite composite() {
         Composite c = new Composite();
         return c;             
     }
}
```

then it's will throw the exception of during bean initialization because of ambiguity with Composite beans so 
here you can use Qualifier to fixed this issue

so

```
@Configuration
 public class SpringConfigA {

@Bean
 @Qualifier("compositeA")
     public Composite composite() {
         Composite c = new Composite();
         return c;             
     }
}
```

and another class SpringConfigB have same Composite bean with Qualifier name "compositeB"

```
@Configuration
 public class SpringConfigB {

@Bean
 @Qualifier("compositeB")
     public Composite composite() {
         Composite c = new Composite();
         return c;             
     }
}
```

Comment: OK so two configuration class are not two different container..  Can you confirm? I don't want to duplicate my component beans because the two configuration class with the same scan package

Comment: Configuration classes are in fact nothing but spring managed factories to create and register bean instances. Two configuration class with the same scan package, this is ok, this is not a issue, spring will take care of it, but make sure you don't have a duplicate bean registers in both   Configuration classes. If you will register a bean with in a Configuration class will applicable for all your application so don't worry about multiple Configuration.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens if i create another class with annotation @Configuration and @Component Scan?

that is ok, is perfectly normal..

> I create another container of beans ? In this way the beans are Duplicates ?

If you create two beans of the same type, you will have an error when the app is starting.. you need to declare one of them as `@Primary`

Comment: The class A with springbootapplication and the class B with Configuration are the same container of beans or two different? If I have a component in a class C.. The system create two instance because there are two configuration?

Comment: all beans are part of the same context.. if A scans B and C.. the context will have two instances of the same bean (defined in B and C), you have to mark one as primary

Answer (score 0):

yes you can register a bean using @ComponentScan by either registering configuration bean in dispatcher servlet or by importing a seperate configuration bean which is lready registered in spring container.
suppose you have Config class in which you are scanning component-

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"xyz"})
@Configuration
public class Config {
....
}
```

To register Config in container you must do-

```
new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext().register(Config .class);
```

Or

```
@Configuration
@Import({MvcConfig.class})
public class AnotherConfig  {
....
}
```

Comment: If I have the class A with springbootapplication  a notion and the class B with Configuration annotation  are the same container of beans or two different? If I have a component in a class C.. The system create two instance because there are two configuration?

Comment: it depends on you whether you want to use it i springbootapplication class or in seperate configuration beans.Spring will do its work anyhow considering it as a single container

Comment: OK so two configuration class are not two different container..  Can you confirm? I don't want to duplicate my component beans because the two configuration class with the same scan package

Comment: please refer this link http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/java-config/

Comment: ok thnx for the link.. the link show to create the context using two config:    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
                  new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class, DataSourceConfig.class);    .... but in spring boot i dont create directly the context... who create the context ? The method SpringApplication.run ? It automatically use all the class with annotation @Configuration ?